# fopen(http://127.0.0.1:3000/.well-known/mercure/): failed to open stream: Failed to parse address &quot;0&quot;

Tags: php, symfony, mercure

I use Symfony 5.1.*. I get this terrible bug, I don't know what's happen, I waste my day for nothing, if any one know something to save my carrier in programming.

```yaml
#.env
MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure/
#config/packages/mercure.yaml
mercure:
    enable_profiler: '%kernel.debug%'
    hubs:
        default:
            url: http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure/
            jwt: '%env(MERCURE_JWT_TOKEN)%'
```

I run the command

```
 ./mercure --jwt-key='!ChangeMe!' --addr='localhost:3000' --allow-anonymous --cors-allowed-origins='http://localhost:8000'
```

Comment: What is "this terrible bug"? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: It's really terible, I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I get a similar error message when I run a console script. The strange thing is that the error message shows an ip-address, while in the .env-file, I use a fqdn. When I access the application via the webserver, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug on the symfony bug tracker: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/38081

The problem was caused by a change in php 7.4.10, that broke symfony/http-client.

**update:** Updating to Symfony 5.1.6 fixed the problem. I guess that for Symfony 4.4 the latest version will fix the problem as well.

Comment: Yes Thank you,  I do and it's work,  but after changinig the hub url from "http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure//" to "http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure". the slash makes diffrence.